# Understanding Davis artificial viscosity

Tags: finite-difference

I'm solving 2D Euler's equations in Cartesian coordinates:
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = 0, \qquad 
U = \left( \begin{array}{c} \rho \\ \rho u \\ \rho v \\ e \end{array} \right), \quad
F = \left( \begin{array}{c} \rho u \\ p+\rho u^2 \\ \rho uv \\ (e+p)u \end{array} \right), \quad
G = \left( \begin{array}{c} \rho v \\ \rho uv \\ p+\rho v^2 \\ (e+p)v \end{array} \right)
$$

using finite difference MacCormack method with Davis artificial viscosity which dampens non-physical oscillations. The MacCormack method is pretty simple and not shown here. Davis viscosity works good in my simulations, but is quite difficult; I'm trying to fully understand it in order to apply it cylindrical coordinates later. I hope that some of you may help me with unclear parts of it (shown in **bold** font below).

Viscous terms are added after 2nd MacCormack step as follows (formulated in 1D for simplicity):
$$
U_j^{n+1}=U_j^{(m)} + \left( D_{j+\frac{1}{2}}-D_{j-\frac{1}{2}} \right),
$$
where $U_j^{(m)}$ denote field values (at $j$-th coordinate point and $(n+1)$-th time layer) calculated by MacCormack scheme as usual, and $D_{j+\frac{1}{2}}, D_{j-\frac{1}{2}}$, are forward and backward differences of U with non-linear coefficients:
$$
D_{j+\frac{1}{2}} := \frac{1}{2} C(\nu_j) \left( 2 - \phi(r_j^+) - \phi(r_{j+1}^-) \right) \Delta U_{j+\frac{1}{2}}, \quad \Delta U_{j+\frac{1}{2}} = U_{j+1} - U_j \\
D_{j-\frac{1}{2}} := \frac{1}{2} C(\nu_{j-1}) \left( 2 - \phi(r_{j-1}^+) - \phi(r_{j}^-) \right) \Delta U_{j-\frac{1}{2}}, \quad \Delta U_{j-\frac{1}{2}} = U_{j} - U_{j-1}
$$

Where $C(\nu)$ is a limited coefficient based on Courant number:
$$
C(\nu) := \begin{cases} \nu(1-\nu) & \;\; \text{if} \;\; \nu \le 0.5 \\ 0.25 & \;\; \text{otherwise} \end{cases}, \qquad \nu = \rho(A(U_j)) \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x},
$$

$A(U)$ is the Jacobian matrix of vector $F$, $\rho(A(U))$ is it's spectral radius **(for Euler's equations it equals $\text{max}(|u|+a, |u|-a)$, where $a$ is the speed of sound)**.

$\phi(r)$ is simple limiting function: $\begin{cases} 0, & r < 0, \\ 2r, & 0 \le r \le 0.5, \\ 1, & r >0.5\\ \end{cases}$

And finally $r_j^+$,$r_j^-$ are slope ratios:
$$
r_j^+ := \frac{\left( \Delta U_{j-\frac{1}{2}}, \Delta U_{j+\frac{1}{2}}\right)}{\left( \Delta U_{j+\frac{1}{2}}, \Delta U_{j+\frac{1}{2}}\right)}, \qquad
r_j^- := \frac{\left( \Delta U_{j-\frac{1}{2}}, \Delta U_{j+\frac{1}{2}}\right)}{\left( \Delta U_{j-\frac{1}{2}}, \Delta U_{j-\frac{1}{2}}\right)}
$$
Where $\left( \cdot , \cdot \right)$ is scalar product. These ratios are positive in monotone areas and negative in non-monotone areas, so that in general coefficients like $\left( 2 - \phi(r_j^+) - \phi(r_{j+1}^-) \right)$ are equal 2 in non-monotone areas; about 1 in monotone, but "curvy" areas; and equal 0 in monotone (and rectilinear) areas.

If both these ($2-\phi-\phi$) coefficients are equal 2, and both $C(\nu)$ are equal 0.25 we have an effective **second derivative of the field value**:
$$
D_{j+\frac{1}{2}}-D_{j-\frac{1}{2}} = 0.25 \left( U_{j+1} - 2U_j + U_{j-1} \right).
$$

**But where is the division by $\Delta x^2$?** If the viscosity would be simply the 2nd derivative, the scheme would look like
$$
U_j^{n+1}=U_j^{(m)} + \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2} \left( U_{j+1} - 2U_j + U_{j-1} \right).
$$
Is $C(\nu)$ effectively equals $\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2}$?

**And, what if $D_{j+\frac{1}{2}}$ is non-zero and $D_{j-\frac{1}{2}}$ is zero?** Does it still yield an effective 2nd derivative?

Comment: $C$ and $D$ just stand for the left and right coefficients for the variation. You are probably confusing them with convection and diffusion. Refer to (2.6) in this paper http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0908002

Comment: @gpavanb In that paper (which is original paper of the method) the letter D is used again with the different meaning, see the unnumbered formula right below (4.14). I'm using that second meaning here.